# EF6 Turning off Lazy Loading returns null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

before I set lazyloading to false. My query returned the correct values, but it brought half the DB with it. I have set lazyloading = false and I have removed the 'Virtual' from both models. But still it returns Null.
Here's my code  : The linq statement

```
public BasePremiumNotional GetBasePremiumNotional(int productVersionId, int bedrooms, string propertyType, int? startYear, int? endYear, DateTime version)
{
            BasePremiumNotional basePremiumNotional =
                GetSingle(t => t.ProductVersionId == productVersionId)
                    .BasePremiumNotionals.FirstOrDefault(
                        g => g.NoOfBedrooms == bedrooms && g.PropertyType == propertyType && g.StartYear == startYear && g.EndYear == endYear && g.Version == version.Date);
            return basePremiumNotional;
}
```

The GetSingle Method to make the actual call:

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = _entities.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return query;
}
```

In this instance `T` is the parent object `ProductVersion` and the child object is `BasePremiumNotionals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with turning off Lazy Loading is that you have to explicitly tell which navigation properties you want to populate along with your query.

To `Include` the navigation properties along with the predicate, you can do:

```
    public T GetSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
               params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {            
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
        }
        return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

And assuming an entity that looks like this:

```
    public class FooBar
    {
        public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BasePremiumNotional> BasePremiumNotionals { get; set; }
    }
```

You can use it as such:

```
var foo = GetSingle<FooBar>(t => t.ProductVersionId == productVersionId, 
                       n => n.BasePremiumNotionals)
```

Comment: When I change the function to this VS's IDE red lines the `navigationProperty` on the Include statement as it cannot resolve  if it should be `System.Data.Entity` or `System.Linq.IQueryable`.

Comment: @bilpor corrected the compile error. also made the second arguments `params` array

Comment: @Aditaya Santoso. Can you give me an example of how I would construct the call to this method, based on my original post. I'm having trouble constructing the second parameter to the method.

Comment: @bilpor edited my answer with sample usage. Although it will help if you can at least post the DTO, or adapt the question to a simplified version of your DTO ...

Comment: Thank you...this has solved my problem. I assume that if I wanted more than 1 include, then `n=> n.BasePremiumNotionals` becomes just a comma separated list of the same. So Id follow it with `,b => b.nextobject` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Turning lazy loading off won't automagically preload the navigation properties with it. In order to get the navigation properties too you need to [Include them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOff) in your query.

Comment: I've been looking at this link, but I cannot add the predicate. So in the `GetSingle` method I start with:  `var query = _entities.Set<T>();` but then if I continue with `_entities.Entry(query).Collection(predicate).Load();` nothing likes the predicate